# How to merge a pull request locally and temporarily

Tags: git, merge, git-rebase, git-flow, pull-request

This is based on the git flow methodology where you have a master and develop branch and features are branched from develop with pull requests from features to develop.

So I've finished working on a feature branch and I've submitted a pull request to get it merged to develop.  Now I want to work on a new feature that has a dependency on the changes in my previous feature.  If I do a merge locally, how do I reconcile after the pull request is eventually approved and develop is ready to be updated?

I'm guessing this will be based around a merge and a rebase but I'm not 100% sure and I don't really want to trash my local repo or end up double committing things.

Comment: You can always just make a copy of your local repo if you are worried about trashing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I've finished working on a feature branch and I've submitted a pull request to get it merged to develop. Now I want to work on a new feature that has a dependency on the changes in my previous feature. If I do a merge locally, how do I reconcile after the pull request is eventually approved and develop is ready to be updated?

Assuming you started with something like:

```
git checkout -b feature/my-feature-1 devel
```

You would start your new feature based on that one:

```
git checkout -b feature/my-feature-2 feature/my-feature-1
```

And do your work on that branch.  Once `my-feature-1` has landed in the `devel` branch, you could rebase `my-feature-2` on the `devel` branch:

```
git checkout feature/my-feature-2
git rebase devel
```

And now you have a branch that is based directly on `devel`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain you can do 
`git rebase origin`
 and that would rebase from the tracking branch of origin.